# Why do I get "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" here?

Tags: scala, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I wanted to hack a quick script that simply splits a nucleotide sequence (a string like "ATGAAGAAC...") into a List of triplets aka codons (Strings: "ATG", "AAG", "AAC", ...) to do other stuff with.

What's wrong with this one-liner, why do I get a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" ?

```
def tripletize(s:String, accu:List[String] = List.empty[String]):List[String] = tripletize(s.drop(3), s.take(3) :: accu)
```

I'm not asking what that is, but why I get it and how to avoid.
Btw, I know this would give me the reverse order, but I don't know how to avoid that scala considers String as a collection itself. i.e. this:

```
scala> List.empty ++ "hello"
res6: List[Char] = List(h, e, l, l, o)
```

Comment: You can do it like this: `s.grouped(3).toList`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When do you stop?  `drop` won't terminate the recursion just because there's nothing more to drop.  Also, what do you return?  You never say.  You need to do something like

```
= if (s.length==0) accu else tripletize(s.drop(3), s.take(3) :: accu)
```

Comment: Small hint: `s.length == 0` equals `s.isEmpty`

Comment: @sschaef - Indeed.  I forgot `isEmpty` was defined on `String`, not just Scala collections.